# Is it acceptable to ignore naming conventions if it makes development easier?

Tags: c#, javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

Usually, when you develop code with Javascript or C#, you use CamelCase for your variables to make the code easier to read.

However, I'm a Dynamics CRM 2011 developer, and one of the quirks of Dynamics CRM has to do with field naming. Basically, if you create a field in Dynamics CRM, it saves the name in 2 different formats: once with with the casing as you enter it (for example: new_SocialSecurityNumber) and once in complete lowercase (for example: new_socialsecuritynumber).

The tricky part is that depending on the context the name is used, you are forced to use a specific version. For example, in Javascript, if you want to get the value of a field from the form, you use lowercase, BUT if you want to retrieve the value using a webservice, you need to use the version with casing (both for the call itself and the return). Similarly, if you're developing in C#, depending on whether you use early or late binding, you either use with or without casing.

now, with Early binding, C# has Intellisense, and with Late binding, it's all lowercase, so that's not that big of a deal, but Javascript has barely any Intellisense related to CRM, and none for field names or webservice related values, so it's a lot easier to work with those fields if you always put the names in lowercase.

Because of the need to use both a correctly cased and a lowercased name of the same field, whenever I create a field in CRM, I'm writing it in full lowercase. This means that both versions of the name are the same, which makes development easier. However, this is not the recommended naming convention for development in C# or Javascript. Is this an acceptable reason to ignore naming conventions? What are the disadvantages of ignoring the naming conventions in this case?

Comment: This is on the edge of an opinion-based answer. It might be better to ask for specific disadvantages of ignoring the naming conventions in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it acceptable to ignore naming conventions if it makes development easier?  Of course.

First off, Guido's answer does an excellent answer of calling out the different areas where the differences in naming convention matter, but I wanted to add some ideas that are not present.

Conventions are created for the sole purpose of making code more uniform, and therefore, more readable between developers.  So the real question is, "does using CamelCase in naming Schema Names in CRM make development easier or harder?"  And to be even more specific, as you state, the intellisense for .net makes case differences "not a big deal", so the real, real question is:

> Does Using CamelCase in naming Schema Names in CRM make it easier when doing development for REST calls?

I say, it depends on the tools that you have.  You've already come to this conclusion yourself with your "not a big deal" for .net development.  I always use LinqPad generate my JavaScript oData calls (There are also other CRM specific OData Helpers, but the full version of LinqPad works great for me).  It provides the intellisense required to keep me from caring if the attributes are correctly CamelCased or not.

**Therefore, for me, no, it does not make development easier and I would therefore keep to the convention.**

Here are some other possibilities to consider.

- VS 2012+ has a very handy "word complete" feature where you can just type the capital letters of the class or property that you're attempting to lookup.  e.g. typeing "contact.FN" would bring up "contact.FullName" in the intellisense.  A very useful feature that you would loose switching over to all lowercase. (you could even change the Early Bound  class creation to still generate correct C# CamelCased properties even when the schema names aren't, but it would require extra work)
- Even if all your custom entities/attributes were all lowercased, the non custom ones would still be CamelCased.
- Readability is hampered in all lower case environment.  e.g. statusstarting vs statUsStarting vs statusStarting vs statusStarTing.  yuck...

Comment: Your first bullet point is not an issue in VS 2015; when I enter a partial name, even if the case is wrong or I'm missing a prefix, VS can still figure out what I meant. This is especially handy since our CRM system has an inconsistent case convention.

Comment: @jpaugh It still stands.  If I have ContactName, ContactId, and ContactSpouse properties, "CN", "CI", and "CS" would be all you have to type in order for VS to be able to autocomplete them for you.  This would be a developer (small) productivity boost, saving a few keystrokes, and helping with spelling as well.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure it still works. The amount of boost would be inversely proportional to the typing speed of the programmer. For me, it's quicker to type out one word than to remember the two words composing it.

Comment: I find it difficult to believe you can type faster than your brain can remember, but if that's the case, then you are choosing the correct method.

Comment: :-) I'm just bad at spelling in my head. I either have to type or speak the phrase to realize which letters are intitials.

Answer (score 2):

As already pointed out this question is a bit borderline here, however let's talk technical:

Dynamics CRM stores the field name with a `Schema Name` and a `Logical Name`.

The `Schema Name` is the one you enter when you create the field and it is case sensitive (this means `new_AccountId` is different from `new_accountid`).

The `Logical Name` is always the lowercase of the `Schema Name`, so if the schema name is `new_ContactId` the logical name will be `new_contactid`

As Dynamics CRM Developer you need handle the field name in these situations:

1. `Xrm` JavaScript object model
2. calls to the `REST` webservices
3. `.NET` code (plugins, custom workflow activities, custom code, ...)

The `Xrm` JavaScript object model uses the logical name, so pretty easy (hide a field, set a value, ...  `Xrm.Page.getAttribute("logicalname").getValue();`)

`REST` calls: the `Schema Name` is used, and there is no alternative, this means you can write your field names in lowercase so the schema name is equals to the logical name, but the OOB fields uses capital letters and more important you are not the customizer of all the CRM environments (this means it's easy to end up working in already customized CRM where the fields name are `new_CountryAreaid` or `new_countryAreaId` instead of `new_countryareaid`)

`.NET Code` this is pretty easy too, if you work with late-bound you need to use logical name, if you work with early-bound the field names are automatically generated, the code will look uglier but nothing dramatic.

Bottom line: I also write the field name in lowercase so the schema name is equals to logical name, but this is my convention (along with other rules) and I apply it when I start to customize a clean CRM instance, but not always when I put my hands inside an already customized CRM.

Advantages vs Disadvantes? This is not the right question. The right questions are:

1. The naming convention is described inside your technical project documentation?
2. All the team members are aware of the naming convention and the corporal punishments* they need to face if they make a mistake? (* I'm joking about this, a salary cut will be enough :D)

Answer (score 0):

The question you should be asking yourself is: **is this name going to be easily understandable by the person who will be maintaining this code six months from now**

If you foresee that the person maintaining a pice of JavaScript code you are writing will be a C# developer, I find perfectly acceptable to skip the conventions and go with the C# style.

Conventions are there to help people to understand code which was not written by them since it would be written in a style they are familiar with, so there is no point in following conventions if they are not going to help in this matter.